# SVN Warning W155010

Tags: linux, svn

When checking out from the repository with `svn co` I get the following error after the checkout:

```
svn: warning: W155010: The node '/path/to/dir' was not found.

svn: E200009: Could not display info for all targets because some targets don't exist
```

However, the directory exists, and all files are checked out accurately, how can I fix that? Is it a server-side problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had a similar case. Please make sure you don't have /path/to/dir as a symbolic link in your repo.

> ls -l /path/to/

lrwxrwxrwx  1 foo bar   13 Sep 30 13:19 dir -> ../../other_dir

In the above case you should perform svn operations on a real path.